# Drupal menu_link with node/number instead of alias

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-path-aliases

I have a problem:

```
 function drupal_menu_link($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  $sub_menu = $element['#below'] ? drupal_render($element['#below']) : '';

  return '<a href="/drupal/'.$element['#href'].'" title = "'.$element['#title'].'" ><li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $element['#title'] .'</li></a>';
}
```

How can I base on aliases, not the hrefs? When I hover on an element I see node/number instead of alias. I made a redirection, but it happens after click. Can somebody help me? I was looking for that in other themes but I am bad at it and I just don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

To transform an node/{number} - url to an existing url_alias, you could use the [url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) method.

```
return '<a href="/drupal/'.url($element['#href']).'" title = "'.$element['#title'].'" ><li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $element['#title'] .'</li></a>';
```

A better way would be, to use the [l](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) method to generate the complete link:

```
return l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], array('attributes'=>$element['#attributes']));
```

Answer (score 0):

To return the path alias, use [drupal_get_path_alias](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7)

```
drupal_get_path_alias("node/" . $nid);
```